# Cmap will only apply to each sphere individually

Tags: python, 3d

I am playing around with 3D graphs, and I created a couple of spheres. How do I make it so that the highest sphere is dark blue and the bottom sphere is white (with the other spheres in between varying in color according to the cmap)?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

theta = np.linspace(0,np.pi,12)
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,12)
u, v = np.meshgrid(theta,phi)

x = []
y = []
z = []

for i in range(5):
    x.append(np.cos(v) * np.sin(u) + i)
    y.append(np.sin(u) * np.sin(v) + i)
    z.append(np.cos(u) + i)
    ax.plot_surface(x[i], y[i], z[i], cmap='Blues')
     
ax.set(xlabel = 'x', ylabel = 'y', zlabel = 'z', xlim = (-10,10), ylim = (-10,10), zlim = (-10,10))
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

I've tried putting `ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='Blues')` after the for loop, but then I always get the error: `'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'`.

My closest attempt has been this:

```
for i in range(5):
    x.append(np.cos(v) * np.sin(u) + i)
    y.append(np.sin(u) * np.sin(v) + i)
    z.append(np.cos(u) + i)
    
X = np.array(x)
Y = np.array(y)
Z = np.array(z)

ax.plot_trisurf(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), Z.flatten(), cmap='Blues')
```

[However, the spheres look all wonky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK3c8.png)

Help appreciated

Comment: Details (screenshot) of how the 'he spheres look all wonky' might help others determine your issue.